# Can electrons be contained to create a battery?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge, capacitance, batteries

Just like gasoline is contained and used as needed can theoretically and erngeneer(ingly?), can electrons be contained and stored in its pure form?
what I mean by pure form is not atached to atoms but be stored by themselves, creating an ultra light weight super powerful battery?

Its been my dream since I have memory (and youtube).

Comment: Isn’t such a charge storage device called a capacitor?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, not if you want them "not attached to atoms".

The impossibility arises because **same charges repel**, no stable system can hold two electrons in a volume unless a lot of energy is supplied, which defeats the plan for a battery, i.e. "a light portable device which stores and supplies energy on demand".

One can control and contain electrons with magnetic and electric fields, but that is a different story than a battery. There are [traps designed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penning_trap) to use for accumulating same charge particles:

> A Penning trap is a device for the storage of charged particles using a homogeneous axial magnetic field and an inhomogeneous quadrupole electric field. This kind of trap is particularly well suited to precision measurements of properties of ions and stable subatomic particles.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly an "electron container", there's an electronic component called a [supercapacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor). They're capacitors on steroids, and they are starting to be used to replace batteries in some applications that do not require high power. Whereas normal capacitors have values in the range of $pF$ to $mF$, supercaps are available up to several $kF$, i.e. their capacity is of the order of a million times larger than electrolytic capacitors.